# Compute probability of next coin toss

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given is a dataset with observations $\{h, t, t, h, t, t, t, t, t, h\}$. To compute the posterior probability function $f$ I assume a uniform Beta Distribution B(1,1)

$ p(\theta) = B(1,1) \cdot\theta^{N_H} \cdot (1-\theta)^{N_T} = B(1,1) \cdot \theta^3 \cdot (1-\theta)^7 $

I want to know the probability that the next toss will be $ h$ using the information given by $f$. Could anyone give me a hint how this works?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the random variable for which $f$ is the density function ? If we know that then we can find the probability using conditioning on that random variable.

Comment: Hi! I edited my question. $p(\theta)$ is the prior function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't make sense.  Your prior distribution for $\theta$ should reflect your belief about the value of the parameter **before** any observations are made.  The posterior represents your belief about the value of the parameter **given** the observed data.  If you assume a uniform prior for $\theta$ and the sampling distribution is Bernoulli, then the posterior is also beta (since the prior is conjugate).

Specifically, if we assume $p(\theta) \sim {\rm Beta}(a,b),$ and we observe in $n$ trials $y$ successes, then the posterior for $\theta$ is $$f(\theta \mid n, y) \sim  {\rm Beta}(a + y, b + n - y).$$  The posterior *predictive* distribution of the next coin flip is Bernoulli, with probability of success equal to $$\Pr[X_{\rm new} = 1] = {\rm E}[\theta \mid n, y] = \frac{a + y}{a+b+n}.$$  In your case, we would simply set $a = b = 1$, $n = 10$, $y = 3$, and just follow the formula.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. Well, in this example we are supposed to calculate the prior distriubution using the given observations. The reason is because we want to know if the coin that's being tossed is fair or biased. Does that make sense to you? Wouldn't $ n = 11 $ since it would be the toss #11?

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding somewhere.  A prior distribution is *never* calculated using the data.  As I said, a prior represents one's belief about the value of the parameter before any data is observed.  A *posterior* is calculated from the prior and the observed data.  $n$ represents the sample size, which in this case is $10$ tosses that you **know** the outcome of.  It absolutely CANNOT be $11$, because if you wanted to estimate the probability of the $11^{\rm th}$ toss, you obviously have not yet observed the outcome of that toss!